# NSString cannot decode class version XXXX

Tags: nsstring, runtime-error, subclassing, nscoder, nsstringencoding

I'm implementing my own keyed `NSCoder` subclass and decoding is failing for an NSString.

If I do something like the following:

```
MyUnarchiver *aDecoder = [[MyUnarchiver alloc] initWithData:someArchivedData];
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCoder:aDecoder];
```

Then the following "uncaught exception" is thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'NSString cannot decode class version 12345'
```

Where 12345 is coming from this method in `MyUnarchiver`, I presume:

```
-(NSInteger)versionForClassName:(NSString *)className
{
    return 12345;
}
```

Similarly, if we throw a `nil` `NSCoder` at `NSString`'s `initWithCoder:` then we get the same error as above, but the version number is 0.

I suspect it might have to do with the fact that I have no idea what I should be implementing in the `versionForClassName:` method. Even from the [Archives and Serializations: Subclassing NSCoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/subclassing.html) reference I'm unable to glean much on this.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand.... in the course of writing out the question, I realized that I hadn't implemented the `allowsKeyedCoding` method, which seems to have at least mitigated the issue.

However, I'm still unsure what should be implemented in `versionForClassName:` if anything. I just deleted it from my implementations and everything seems to be working just as well.

Hope this helps someone.